# Background image doesn't appear IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have this location link beside which i have placed a background image as following

```
<div class="rightLinks homeLocalChange">
    <a href="#" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://mypreviewdev.okla.seagate.com/portal/site/myseagate/menuitem.a7093785094fba806b42d710f014a_21&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">ChangeLocation</a>
</div>

.threeCols .box .rightLinks a 
{
  background:url('../images/icn/icn_arrow_configure.png')no-repeat 95px 9px;
}
```

but somehow the image just appears perfect in FF /Chrome but in IE it just doesn't shows up.

even inside developer it wont even show up the css i have given.

i use IE8

Comment: Please update your answer you are missing something... like links and your code is not showing too.

Comment: And you seem to be missing an opening parenthesis between the `url` and the `'..images`

Comment: Oops my bad ! i did it now. So there is this div which has a anchor tag which im targeting through css and giving it a bg but somehow it just doesn't comeup in IE

Comment: Can you create the fiddle for this issue so we can see how the images is appearing in different browsers. Right now we dont have the image and the whole css too. can you please dot it...

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding space after `)` before `no-repeat`

```
.threeCols .box .rightLinks a { 
   background:url('../images/icn/icn_arrow_configure.png') no-repeat 95px 9px; 
}
```

Comment: In my case this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving width and height

```
.threeCols .box .rightLinks a 
{
  background:url('../images/icn/icn_arrow_configure.png')no-repeat 95px 9px;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;

}
```